# How to inject parameter with ParameterizedCommand in Eclipse 4.3?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am currently implementing an Eclipse 4.3 application and running into a problem. I try to parametrize a command to delete specific files. My approach is corresponding to [Getting parameter of parameterized command in Eclipse RCP 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852088/getting-parameter-of-parameterized-command-in-eclipse-rcp-4-2), but i somehow don't get it working right.

In my Application.e4xmi I have added a command with a parameter:

```
<commands xmi:id="_K1MVgDGKEeOO8o2ChqdHMA" elementId="first.application.command.deleteproject" commandName="deleteProjectCommand">
<parameters xmi:id="_Hr4FEDGTEeOO8o2ChqdHMA" elementId="cmd0" name="cmd0" typeId="" optional="false"/>
</commands>
```

At one point in my code I create the command, set the parameter, and execute it:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("cmd0", "test");
final Command command =commandService.getCommand("first.application.command.deleteproject");
final ParameterizedCommand pcmd = ParameterizedCommand.generateCommand(command, parameters);
pcmd.executeWithChecks(null, null);
```

I have a handler that is linked with the command, that has the following execute method:

```
@Execute
public void execute(@Optional @Named("cmd0") String file) {
  System.out.println("delete project " + file);
}
```

Everything works fine, only the `file` is not injected, it stays `null`. When I check the `pcmd` variable before I execute it, it tells me that it has set the parameters correctly to `{cmd0=test}` (using `System.out.println(pcmd.getParameterMap());`). When I remove `@Optional`, the execute method is not called at all.

Somewhere the parameter `cmd0` is lost. Where is the mistake in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the solution. Executing with `pcmd.executeWithChecks(null, null);` seems not to work as expected. Instead, we need the `EHandlerService` that we inject:

```
@Inject
private EHandlerService handlerService;
```

And now we execute the command with the service like this:

```
handlerService.executeHandler(pcmd);
```

Voila!

I hope this can help someone, too.