# How to create parameters for e4 commands

Tags: parameters, command, e4

I am working on an e4 application trying to pass parameters to a command.
I defined the parameters in the application model hence they are Strings.
I left out the typeId for the parameters.

```java
Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameter.put("de.mdsd.e4.rap.kdn.joggathon.webeditor.commandparameter.username", username);
parameter.put("de.mdsd.e4.rap.kdn.joggathon.webeditor.commandparameter.password", password);
ParameterizedCommand cmd = commandService.createCommand("command.dologin", parameter );
```

When I create the command passing the parameters I get null back because the commandService does not find a converter for my parameters.

Which typeId I have to specify in the parameters to get simple String parameters working ?

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19293503/2670892

Answer (score 0):

Your version is perfectly fine, in case "*username*" and "*password*" are from type `String`. The error is probably produced somwhere else. 
You could try `parameters.clear();` before filling your map to avoid an unexpected mapping.